# How to say "the payment cleared"?

Tags: traducción, finanzas

I want to tell a friend that his credit card payment for an airline ticket went through (or was approved).  How do I say that?

(In case your wondering why he doesn't call and ask himself, it's a german company and he only speaks spanish and portuguese.)

Answer (score 7):

At least in Mexico, you can say:

> Ya pasó el pago. (this is the most common)
>   Ya (fue aprobado | te aprobaron) el pago.
>   Ya (fue aceptado | te aceptaron) el pago.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to say it is:

> Amigo, el pago que hiciste con tu tarjeta de crédito para comprar los pasajes ya fue autorizado

By the way, the word "Autorizado" conveys the proper meaning and is also the word commonly used in the financial world.

Answer (score 2):

In general I think it is safe to say the following:

> Su pago ha terminado exitosamente
>
> La transacción ha finalizado de manera exitosa

More informal, for your friend

> Tu pago terminó bien

or even

> Tu pago fue bien

Answer (score 2):

The *Payment has been cleared* phrase can be translated as:

1.- El pago ha sido aceptado. (Payment has been accepted)
2.- El pago fue aprobado.  (Payment has been approved)
3.- El pago fue verificado. (Payment has been verified)
3.- El pago se efectuó de manera correcta. (The payment has been processed correctly)
4.- El pago fué satisfactorio. (The payment was satisfactory)

All of these phrases refer to the payment process, particularly related to online or electronic transactions.

All though all five phrases have a literal translation, (in parentheses)all are used to state the same process.